# можно ли применять на один шаблон 2 или более моделей в Джанго

Tags: python, django, django-model

Можно ли применять на один шаблон 2 или более моделей.
вот код моделей

```
class Goods(models.Model):
    description_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description_text

    def __str__(self):
        return self.price_text


class Number(models.Model):
    number1_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    number2_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.number1_text

    def __str__(self):
        return self.number2_text
```

они должны применятся на шаблон index.html

для этого я добавил ещё один класс к views.py с одним и тём же шаблоном как у IndexView, я подумал что эти классы по дельности будут отображать свою модель но при этом на один шаблон index.html, однако не удивительно что ничего не работает). Прошу помочь, и не судить строго так как я новичок в Джанго и ещё не особо понимаю как работает этот фреймворк, если какие-то неувязочки в формулировании вопроса так же извиняюсь.

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'Homepage/index.html'
    model = Goods
    context_object_name = 'goods'


    def description(self):
        return self.description_text

    def price(self):
        return self.price_text

class NumbersView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'Homepage/index.html'
    model = Number
    context_object_name = 'numbers'

    def number1(self):
        return self.number1_text

    def number2(self):
        return self.number2_text
```

Comment: Каждый класс это, грубо говоря отдельная вьюха. Вам Нужно определить модели и передать их в контекст в пределах одного класса... Я бы наследовал IndexView не от ListView, а от View и переопределил метод get

Comment: @Uncle_Ragnar Можете показать на моём коде а то я не особо понимаю что делать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**URLS.PY**

```
path('index_page', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
class IndexView(View):
    model1 = Goods
    model2 = Number
    template = 'Homepage/index.html'
    context = {}

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.context = {
            'goods': self.model1.objects.all()
            'numbers': self.model2.objects.all()
        }
        return(render(request, self.template, self.context))
```

**INDEX.HTML**

```
{% for good in goods %}
    <p>{{ good.нужное поле или метод }}</p>
{% endfor %}

{% for number in numbers %}
    <p>{{ number.нужное поле или метод }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Могут быть грамматические ошибки, так что лучше не копипастить.

Comment: Не роботает, выдаёт ошибку с request

Comment: Покажите трэйсбэк.

Comment: возможно скобки лишние - `return render(request, self.template, self.context)`

Comment: О, совсем забыл... В функцию нужно принять реквест: def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):